# OIDC/OAuth2: session management on the server side

Tags: web, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I am using the OIDC protocol in order to perform authentication.

The flow that i'm using is the `authorization code` flow.

When a user authenticates through the Authorization Server, my client application backend receives an `id_token` containing information about the user.

At this point, i consider him as authenticated since i can verify the claims inside the `id_token` and validate the signature.

I would like to keep my own cookie based session and ignore the `id_token` after i'm done with authentication, of course i would extract some of the claims from the token but i don't want to use any refresh token. In fact i would like to have my own session expiration time.

I don't care if the user claims change on the Resource Server side while my application session is still active and based on old claims.

Is it secure enough ? Should i only rely on `id_token` and refresh it after it expires ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it secure enough ?

It depends on what you want to be protected from. Are you using PKCE with `authorization_code`?

> Should i only rely on id_token and refresh it after it expires ?

I would suggest you throw away the ID Token and call explicitly with the Access Token the `user_info` endpoint to retrieve User claims so that you don't have to handle in your Client the crypto material required to verify the ID Token "authenticity". Even if you can download the public key from the `jwks_uri`, there is only one way to ensure that the token is legit, it is to request the one who forged it. Cryptographic verification of the ID Token to gain trust on it is acceptable when you are in a trusted zone only.

In order to harden things, check if your Authorization Server supports more modern client authentication (client_secret_jwt, private_key_jwt). So that your client authentication doesn't transmit the client secret in clear text but create an ephemeral JWT and sign it with HMAC(ClientSecret) for `client_secret_jwt` or a concrete private key for `private_key_jwt`)

## Reference(s)

- https://oauth.net/2/pkce/
- https://kb.authlete.com/en/s/oauth-and-openid-connect/a/client-secret-jwt
- https://kb.authlete.com/en/s/oauth-and-openid-connect/a/client-auth-private-key-jwt

Comment: I am not using PKCE, i'm only using the authorization code flow. I don't really want to call the userinfo endpoint because it's more overhead on the network. The id token really contains all the information that i need. I am not verifying the signature in my own code, i use Spring Security for that.

Comment: "Cryptographic verification of the ID Token to gain trust on it is acceptable when you are in a trusted zone only."

What do you mean by that ?

Comment: If you authenticate an ID token using a public key, it just proves that the ID token integrity is conserved and has been signed by the owner of the private key. Now if the private leaks, you won't have any countermeasure to detect whether the ID token has been generated by the AS or not. Also, ID Tokens have been designed for frontend usages (in hybrid flow) where nothing could be trusted. The backend should use the `user_info` endpoint to retrieve the user session attributes, it's not a huge cost, it's just one after Access token retrieval and use its claims to create local identity.